# Using symbols for products in xy-pic

Tags: xy-pic, commutative-diagrams

I am trying to make a diagram in xy-pic with the xy-matrix environment where I need to have a node which is product of sets like, but I always seem to get a compilation error when I try to use the command for products within an xymatrix environment:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\CompileMatrices
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \xymatrix{
  \prod_{i:I} A_i \ar@<-.5ex>[r]_c \ar@<.5ex>[r]^d & \prod_{j:J} A_j
  }
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

But when I try to compile this I get the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...COORD@ =\xymatrixCOORD@ \prodop \kp
@slimits _{i:I} A_i \ar @<...
l.19 \xy@{\save }{\save@ }
%
```

Any help with how to get this working is much appreciated since I haven't been able to find anyone here with similar problems.

EDIT: After having messed around with the code, it seems like the error arises because of the `\CompileMatrices` command in the preamble.

Comment: Erh, if you start by making this into a real doc with `\begin{document}` in its proper place and adding say `\documentclass{article}`, then your MWE compiles for me. What exactly is your question?

Comment: After adding `\documentclass{article}` and moving `\begin{document}` to the proper place, I get no error from the example. The error message suggests you're using the `kpfonts` package: please make a better example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of Xy-pic:

> ### 1.7 Speeding up typesetting
>
> One thing that you will notice is that Xy-pic is sometimes slow in typesetting diagrams (this is to be expected considering the number of drawing operations performed as reflected by the number last in each `xymatrix` message). If you follow the rule of **starting all entries with a (nonexpandable) character or `{`** then you can insert the declaration
>
> ```
> \CompileMatrices
> ```
>
> in the preamble of your document: this will create temporary files containing *compiled* versions of each matrix that can be loaded very quickly; they are automatically recreated when a matrix is changed.

I added the boldface for emphasis.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\CompileMatrices
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \xymatrix{
  \relax\prod_{i:I} A_i \ar@<-.5ex>[r]_c \ar@<.5ex>[r]^d & \relax\prod_{j:J} A_j
  }
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

On the other hand, compiling matrices is nowadays unnecessary, as machines are fast enough.

[image]

Alternative:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\CompileMatrices
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \xymatrix{
  {\prod_{i:I} A_i} \ar@<-.5ex>[r]_c \ar@<.5ex>[r]^d & {\prod_{j:J} A_j}
  }
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

By the way, loading `amssymb` and `amsfonts` along with `kpfonts` is unnecessary, because the package will override them anyhow.